# What is the device used in Captain America: Civil War to disable the electical substation?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

In *Captain America: Civil War* the main antagonist, Helmut Zemo, uses a device to disable an electrical substation.

What is that device called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a device for generating an EMP ([**Electro-Magnetic Pulse**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_pulse))

> An electromagnetic pulse (EMP), also sometimes called a transient electromagnetic disturbance, is a short burst of electromagnetic energy. Such a pulse's origination may be a natural occurrence or man-made and can occur as a radiated, electric, or magnetic field or a conducted electric current, depending on the source.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_pulse)</sup>

Such devices can vary in size from small hand-held devices to large "guns" and, for the purposes of the movie, large area devices.

**EMP "Guns"**

[image][image]